# Access on-premises Office365/AD from Azure Web app

Tags: active-directory, azure

I'm currently working on a web app that is deployed to a server on our (company) domain. We're looking to migrate to Azure. Migrating our whole AD to Azure is out of our scope at the moment.

Now, my question is: **Is there a way to acess on-premises Active Directory or Office 365 from my app deployed to Azure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that once you migrate your Web App to Azure your plan is to authenticate your on-premises users with Active Directory. If that is the case you don't need to *migrate* your AD to Azure, you just need to do password synchronization to Azure Active Directory using [Azure AD Connect.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-express)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. It was kinda hard to find among all other Azure features.